# How to get the "LastLogon" time stamp for users from Active Directory

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am creating an app to display the users last logon time stamp as well as date created and a few other info.  How do I get the lastlogon to display in my listview?

I have tried various solutions on SO as well as various other websites but none seems to be working

This is the code I am using to display the information needed

```
lvwListView.Clear();
lvwListView.Columns.Add("Name", 175, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
lvwListView.Columns.Add("LanID", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
lvwListView.Columns.Add("Email", 225, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
lvwListView.Columns.Add("Phone Number", 150, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
lvwListView.Columns.Add("When Created", 150, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
lvwListView.Columns.Add("Last Logon", 150, HorizontalAlignment.Left);

if (results != null)
{
    foreach (Principal p in results)
    {
        itmListItem = new ListViewItem();
        itmListItem.Text = p.Name;
        itmListItem.SubItems.Add(p.SamAccountName);

        if (p.StructuralObjectClass == "user")
        {
            var uP = (UserPrincipal)p;
            if (uP != null)
            {
                itmListItem.SubItems.Add(uP.EmailAddress);
            }
        }

        var creationDate = string.Empty;
        var telephoneNumber = string.Empty;
        var lastLogon = string.Empty;
        var prop = string.Empty;
        var directoryEntry = p.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
        prop = "whenCreated";
        if (directoryEntry.Properties.Contains(prop))
        {
            creationDate = directoryEntry.Properties[prop].Value.ToString();
        }
        prop = "telephoneNumber";
        if (directoryEntry.Properties.Contains(prop))
        {
            telephoneNumber = directoryEntry.Properties[prop].Value.ToString();
        }
        prop = "lastLogon";
        if (directoryEntry.Properties.Contains(prop))
        {
            lastLogon = directoryEntry.Properties[prop].Value.ToString();
        }

        itmListItem.SubItems.Add(telephoneNumber);
        itmListItem.SubItems.Add(creationDate);
        itmListItem.SubItems.Add(lastLogon);
        lvwListView.Items.Add(itmListItem);
        lvwListView.Refresh();
        itmListItem = null;
        this.Text = Application.ProductName + " (" + groupName + ")";
    }

    ctx.Dispose();
}
```

The code above displays the `Name`, `LanId`, `Email`, `phone number` and `when created` perfectly, but for the `lastlogon` it displays `System._ComObject`.

I don't fully understand why it will display the `WhenCreated` but not the `lastLogon`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WhenCreated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/adschema/a-whencreated) is stored as [String (Generalized-Time) type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/adschema/s-string-generalized-time), whereas [Last-Logon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/adschema/a-lastlogon) is stored as [Interval syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/adschema/s-interval), which is convertible to an [IADsLargeInteger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/iads/nn-iads-iadslargeinteger).

Here's an example extension that will convert that to a familiar `System.DateTime`:

```
public static class ActiveDirectoryExtensions
{
    public static DateTime GetLastLogon(this DirectoryEntry entry)
    {
        var activeDirectoryLargeInteger = (IAdsLargeInteger)entry.Properties["lastLogon"].Value;
        return DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc((activeDirectoryLargeInteger.HighPart << 32) + activeDirectoryLargeInteger.LowPart);
    }

    [ComImport, Guid("9068270b-0939-11d1-8be1-00c04fd8d503"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
    internal interface IAdsLargeInteger
    {
        long HighPart { get; set; }

        long LowPart { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Usage:

`var lastLogon = directoryEntry.GetLastLogon()`

Comment: Hi, thanks for explaining to me the difference between the `whenCreated` and `lastLogon`.  I am still having trouble implementing your code to my existing code.

Comment: Basically, just copy and paste `ActiveDirectoryExtensions` as a new class in your project in the same namespace as your code. Then, change `lastLogon = directoryEntry.Properties[prop].Value.ToString();` to `lastLogon = directoryEntry.GetLastLogon().ToString();`

Answer (score 0):

I use NET 4.8    .

```
public static class ActiveDirectoryExtendetMethod
        {
            public static Object GetPropertyValue(this SearchResult sr, string propertyName)
            {
                DateTime GetLastLogon(object value)
                {
                    var intVal = (Int64)value;
                    return DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(intVal);
                }
    
                if (sr.Properties[propertyName].Count > 0)
                {
                    if (propertyName == "lastLogon")
                    {
                        return GetLastLogon(sr.Properties[propertyName][0]).ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return sr.Properties[propertyName][0].ToString();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
```